# Unique combination of 2 columns into a variable

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get a unique combination of columns B and C using Excel VBA.

I'm doing this to then be able to automatically filter from columns B and C and send an email for each unique combination of the two. What is the best way to obtain the unique combination?

[image]

I'm thinking of something along the lines of
put unique combination of B and C into 2 dimensional list "L"

```
for i,j in l do:
    filter criteria B = "i"
    filter criteria C = "j"
    run my email macro 
end;
```

Comment: Could you please show us your attempt? There are a lot of ways to approach this.

Comment: It's been 10 years since I did VBA macros so any suggestion is welcome :)

Comment: So Apple1 is unique and the place doesn't matter for what you need? Then you can just use a dictionary and use the keys to send your email with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always find unique values by attempting to add them to a collection while also using them as the key. Because items in a collection each must have a unique key, only unique items will be allowed into the collection. Here is the code:

```vb
Sub uniqueFruitCombo()
    Dim rng As Range, arr() As Variant, uniqueFruitNumberCollection As Collection, delimiter As String
    Set rng = Range("B2:C8")
    arr = rng
    Set uniqueFruitNumberCollection = New Collection
    
    delimiter = "!" 'specify delimiter here
    
    Dim val As String
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        val = arr(i, 1) & delimiter & arr(i, 2)
        On Error Resume Next
            uniqueFruitNumberCollection.Add val, val
        On Error GoTo -1
    Next i
    
    For Each x In uniqueFruitNumberCollection
        Debug.Print "B value: " & Split(x, delimiter)(0) & ", C value: " & Split(x, delimiter)(1)
    Next x
End Sub
```

**output:**

```
B value: apple, C value: 1
B value: banana, C value: 1
B value: banana, C value: 2
B value: apple, C value: 3
B value: banana, C value: 4
```

Comment: Sorry I should have specified I wanted the output to be a 2 variable list so that i can unpack it in a loop. so variable i would be fruit and variable j would be the number

Comment: @Mobix you can concatenate the values and put some delimiter in between which is not normally present in either column (I used exclamation mark here but change it to whatever you want). Once you obtain the unique combinations, you can split the values with the split() function. I modified the code.